# CoordinatorLayout fill remaining height

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

With a `CoordinatorLayout`, if it contains two views and one view is docked to the bottom `layout_gravity="bottom"`, can I make the other view fill the remaining height? For example, if the screen height is 1000dp, and the bottom view's height is 300dp, the other view's height should be 700dp.

This would be easy with a `LinearLayout`, but to use a Bottom Sheet, I must set a `CoordinatorLayout` as the topmost layout. And I wonder if there is a way to get what I want without adding a child `LinearLayout` to wrap the two views.

Comment: post the tried xml !

Comment: I could not get it work with the CoordinatorLayout at all, so I just wrapped the two with a LinearLayout.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this onto your upper view's XML definition:

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`